# Is there a way to monitor pending request for gRPC server in C++

Tags: c++, grpc, interceptor

We are using gRPC C++ library, 1.36.0. The number of max concurrent streams are set to, for example, 200. We are using gRPC in async mode and serval worker threads (for example, 4 worker threads) are set to processing the requests.

My question is if there is a way to monitor current on-going concruurent streams at a certain time? (Requests are queued but not processed by worker threads.) The complete queue does not expose a method to get current queue size.